# Is it possible to extend Lync incoming call popup?

Tags: lync, lync-2010, lync-server-2010, lync-client-sdk

Currently I'm seeing only phone number of the caller. Is it possible to extend incoming call popup(add additional information querying DB by phone number) ?

I'm using Lync SDK 2010.

[image: Incoming call popup]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possilbe.

You can instead hook into the Lync client using the SDK, catch the incoming call event, and display a second popup with your own data. Some styling and positioning would make it near perfect.

Comment: That's what i thought. I already do have this app... client isn't happy to install it as a separate app. But thanks anyway. Will wait a bit and mark as an answer.

Comment: Had same problem here, even contacted Microsoft about it, but short from writing your own Lync client, there is nothing we can do.